# How to enable an user to access a specific S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket and I created an IAM user, I would like to give this user the ability to access the S3 bucket using a client like `CyberDuck`. I tried to create a policy but the user can't access. What I have to do more?

This is modified version of my policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::MY_ROOT_USER_ID:user/IAM_USER"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn_of_my_bucket/*"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Are you able to list objects inside the bucket?

Answer (score 0):

Does not sound really secure, but the trick here is to mount the bucket to a server and then connect to it via the server.

you might find this usefull as well:

[AWS S3 (s)FTP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_amazon_s3_sftp)

Comment: I really like this solution

Comment: I tried it. I got the s3fs working, I have the sftp access, but I can't get the user connected to be able to access the mounted bucket. What I'm doing now is coping the bucket files on the server, but I'm lucky that are not so much files.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a JSON policy as below & attach it to the IAM user -

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

IAM user should now be able to list the bucket & objects both.

Comment: Tried. Didn't work. I can get the connection, but the listing of the objects is denied. I think that the policy must be applied to the bucket and not to the IAM role

Comment: I have tried this policy with IAM user & Roles, both work fine. You don't need any bucket policy. Probably you can try this using AWS CLI.